# Убрать последнюю часть после разделителя

Tags: регулярные-выражения, excel

Здравствуйте, как удалить последнюю часть в этой строке?

`Лакокрасочные материалы~Краски водно-дисперсионные~Краски Фасадные~Краска фасадная RAUF R351 матовая, латексная, белая 14кг`.

А именно
`~Краска фасадная RAUF R351 матовая, латексная, белая 14кг`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текст без правой части после последнего разделителя:

```
=ЛЕВБ(A1;ПОИСК("\";ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;"~";"\";ДЛСТР(A1)-ДЛСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;"~";))))-1)
```

Правая часть текста после последнего разделителя:

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПРАВБ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;"~";ПОВТОР(" ";999));999))
```

Если  в тексте фрагмент не повторяется (или одиннаковые фрагменты нужно удалить со всего текста), можно так:

```
=ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;"~"&СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПРАВБ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;"~";ПОВТОР(" ";999));999));)
```

Получить предпоследний фрагмент:

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ЛЕВБ(ПРАВБ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;"~";ПОВТОР(" ";999));2000);999))
```

Comment: а как получить предпоследнюю часть между последним разделителем и предпоследним разделителем?:)

Comment: спасибо,не стал ерундить,а на момент создания экселя просто правильно вытащил нужную инфу

Comment: @hunter, таким "финтом" можно получать любой фрагмент текста между разделителями. Добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте пользовательскую функцию:

```
Public Function TruncateLast(arg As Range, delim As String) As String
Application.Volatile
If InStr(arg.Value, delim) = 0 Then
    TruncateLast = arg.Value
Else
    TruncateLast = Left(arg.Value, InStrRev(arg.Value, delim) - 1)
End If
End Function
```

И соответственно

```
 B1 = TruncateLast(A1;"~")
```

Comment: спасибо, за помощь!

Answer (score -1):

Найденную регуляркой

```
/~[^~]+$/
```

подстроку следует заменить на пустую строку.

Пример https://regex101.com/r/QVB0Sx/1

P.S. С Excel не работал более 7 лет ;)

Comment: спасибо, за помощь!